# Key combination not working in Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, swt, keylistener

In my Eclipse RCP application, which is for both Windows and Ubuntu Linux, I want to prevent user from copying and pasting the data. I have successfully prevented in Windows, BUT on Ubuntu 12.04, the same code is not working. Following is the code, which works on Windows -

```
htmlBrowser.addListener(SWT.KeyDown, new Listener()
{
    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event e)
    {
          if ((e.stateMask & SWT.CTRL) == SWT.CTRL && e.keyCode == 'c')
          {
              e.doit = false;
          }
    }
});
```

In the above condition, the flow in NOT entering.

Any help?

Comment: What kind of `Listener` do you use? Moreover: Do both parts evaluate to `false` or just one of them. If only one, which one?

Comment: Update the post with the more code. Which listener are you using: Typed and Untyped?. If THE SAME CODE is working on Windows and NOT on Ubuntu then I think it is a bug in SWT. You can log bug [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/)

Comment: @ChandrayyaGK Hold your horses :D Before posting it as a bug, you should make sure that it actually is a bug.

Comment: Just tested it on Linux Mint (Ubuntu derivative) and it works just fine... You'll have to post more code to see what's going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, tested this on Linux Mint and it works perfectly. Just listen for `SWT.KeyDown` and check if the user pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> and set `event.doit` to `false`:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

    Text text = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);
    text.addListener(SWT.KeyDown, new Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event e)
        {
            if ((e.stateMask & SWT.CTRL) == SWT.CTRL && e.keyCode == 'c')
            {
                e.doit = false;
            }
        }
    });

    shell.setSize(1000, 400);
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

Comment: @Baz- I have updated the code using your logic, BUT still not working.

Comment: @Baz- Well to add more to this issue, you have used `Text` component and I am using `Browser`. I tried your code with `Text`, it works fine.

Comment: @John SWT `Browser` is a tricky piece of code. It seems to fire the `Listener` just fine, but ignores `e.doit = false`. I'm almost certain that there is nothing you can do about it from the SWT side of things. You could however place an invisible `div` above the content you don't want anyone to copy to prevent selection altogether.